# What does || ' ' || mean in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I find a query oracle type that i never use oracle.
Here the code.

```
SELECT fst_name || ' ' || last_name
              FROM siebel.s_contact 
             WHERE row_id = t41.pr_con_id
```

what does `|| ' ' ||` it means? i asume that character is for join two field like `fst_name` + `last_name` into `full_name` ??
Thank you

Comment: `||`  is the string concatenation operator in SQL.

Comment: is my asume right? that the result is full_name?

Comment: Literally, what you wrote concatenates FIRST NAME with a **SPACE** character and LAST NAME. So, yes - that's someone's full name.

Comment: It depends: sometimes "firstname + lastname" is not enough for the full name (depends on what you store). In some cultures the family name comes first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL `||` operator allows you to concatenate 2 or more strings together.

Example:
varchar 1: Harry -
Varchar 2: Mueller

You can concatenate this two with `||` operator:

```
Select 'Harry' || 'Mueller' from dual:
```

output:

```
HarryMueller
```

But with a space you can seprate these two. You can add a space between two varchar with a `' '` :

```
Select 'Harry' || ' ' || 'Mueller' from dual:
```

output:

```
Harry Mueller
```

Comment: It is not just the Oracle concatenation operator, it is the Standard SQL concatenation operator.

Answer (score 0):

As Rezu said, it's a concatenation operator.  I find I most often use this when I need to spit out a large number of SQL Statements to act on data in the DB, especially with CHR(39), which gives us a single quote.  As a simple example, say you need to populate a QA environment, so you just want to use the data that you already generated in your DEV environment.

```
SELECT 'INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS 
(NAME, ID) 
VALUES
(' || CHR(39) || NAME || CHR(39) || ',' || ID || ');';
```